# Drawing collider boundaries (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

everyone!

I ran into the problem. I need to draw a radius of enemy attack. The radius needs to be equal radius of SphereCollider that is hanging on it. I've tried to do it with the help of LineRenderer which draws circle. Yeah, actually it draws circle correctly, but the radius of my circle is less than radius of collider on it, despite the fact that I've given the value of a variable from the GetComponent().

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Part of my code:

```
    float x;
    float z;

    float change = 2 * (float)Math.PI / segments;
    float angle = change;

    x = Mathf.Sin(angle) * radius;
    _line.SetPosition(0, new Vector3(x, 0, Mathf.Cos(angle) * radius));

    for (int i = 1; i < (segments + + 2); i++)
    {
        x = Mathf.Sin(angle) * radius;
        z = Mathf.Cos(angle) * radius;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(drawSpeed);
        _line.SetPosition((int)i, new Vector3(x, 0, z));

        angle += change;
    }
```

Comment: Well .. what is your `radius` and where did you get it from? And also note that the final size of the collider is also depending on the lossy scale (all parent and this local scales combined) of your object

Comment: does that "Gizmos" thing in unity help here ?

Comment: @Fattie sounds like it should be in a built not in the SceneView

Comment: @derHugo i don't understand what's mean "what is your radius". I just have a private variable "radius" and define It something like this: "radius = _collider.radius". But you told me about lossy scale and because of this I have a quistion how to get me finel size of my collider?

Comment: @gh272b see that's what I assumed but without seeing it in your code how should we know where you get the value of the radius from? ;) Now the next question is: Is your object or any of its parent objects somehow scaled different to `1,1,1`? .. also is that `segments + + 2` a typo?

Comment: @derHugo 'Yeah, segments + + 2" is a typo and I'm changed scale only in a parent object

Comment: I suspected that and just added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65437508/7111561) that should deal with that changed scaling ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments you mentioned that you get your radius from

```
float radius = _collider.radius;
```

where `_collider` is your `SphereCollider`.

So note that the [`SphereCollider.radius`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SphereCollider-radius.html)

> The radius of the sphere measured in the **object's local space**.
>
> The sphere radius will be scaled by the transform's scale.

It appears to me that either your object or one of its parent is somehow scaled differently than `1,1,1` in which case the actual final radius will be influenced by that scale.

You would need to scale the radius accordingly by the [`transform.lossyScale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-lossyScale.html) like e.g.

```
// Get the lossyScale
// this is the localScale of all parent objects and this localScale combined
var lossyScale = _collider.transform.lossyScale;

// find the biggest extends of the lossyScale
// if you already know they are always equal anyway simply use e.g. lossyScale.x instead   
float maxScale = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
   maxScale = Mathf.Max(maxScale, Mathf.Abs(lossyScale[i]);
}

float radius = _collider.radius * maxScale;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hacky, but I've used a sphere outline sprite for just this sort of thing. Just put it on the game object and make sure it is scaled same as your collider. No need for fancy line drawing.

Answer (score 0):

### Don't use collider component for the enemy attack range!

Instead of adding a **circle collider component** you should **a collider via code & physics**.

### What should you do?

This is an example of using **a collider via code & physics**:

```
float theCircleRadios = /* You radios */;
Collider2D[] detectedEnemiesColliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(theCirclePosition, theCircleRadios, DetectedLayers);
```

Then make your line `lineRenderer radios == theCircleRadios`.

Comment: It's a variant, but to do it, I'm need to change a huge part of my code. And I also knew about this feature of Unity and used it at the beginning but in this project it's hard to realise and I decided to it with colliders. But thanks anyway for your advice!